# Is it possible to move the contents of a variable directly into a register in SuperH assembly?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

Let's say I have some variable defined:

```
myvar: .byte 0x20
```

Is it possible to move the contents of this variable (ie 0x20) directly into a register? For example: (not sure what the syntax would look like if this was possible of course)

```
mov.b (myvar), r4
```

From the SH-1/SH-2/SH-DSP programming manual, it looks like this is not supported, but I want to be sure.

Comment: No.  The instructions are not big enough to hold a complete address.  You'll have to move the address into a register and fetch through @r3.